# My PHP isn't Fetching data from MySql

Tags: php, mysql, fetch

I am creating a Login form that captures the values so I can use throughout the session when the user gets pass the regular Login page. I have input in MySQL as follows:

user_id 
| username 
| password 
| firstname 
| lastname 
| email 
| website 
| active 
| date_added

I created a function to capture data but it doesn't return anything. Can anyone help me with this?

Here is what the code looks like:

```
 function user_input($user_id) {
 $input = array();
 $user_id = (int) $user_id;

 $func_num_args = func_num_args();
 $func_get_args = func_get_args();

 if ($func_num_args > 1) {
 unset($func_get_args[0]);

 $fields = ' ` ' . implode('`, ` ', $func_get_args) . ' `';


 $query = mysql_query("SELECT '$fields' FROM Login WHERE user_id = '$user_id' ");
 $input = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);


 print_r($input);
 }
 }
```

Comment: why single quotes `('$fields')` when you already added back-ticks

Comment: Please stop using `mysql_*` functions, they are [**deprecated**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Comment: Casting to `(int)` is a really poor substitution for [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 private function user_input($user_id) {

 private $input = array();
 //$user_id = (int) $user_id; //This line may effect your security 

if(isset($input)){

 $func_num_args = func_num_args();
 $func_get_args = func_get_args();

$query = "SELECT ";
for($i = 0 ; $i <=  $func_num_args; $i++){

     if($i==($func_num_args-1))
     {
         $query =$query .$func_get_args[$i];
     }
     else
     {
         $query =$query .$func_get_args[$i].",";
     }

    }
    $query = $query . " FROM Login WHERE `user_id` =" . $user_id ;

   $rs = mysql_query($query);

    while ($getRow = Mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
       self::$input = $getRow;
    }
 }
    return self::$input ; // this will be returning an array of result set 


  }
```

Comment: Wow this site is incredible. Thanks for writing the function for me. I wish I had your brain. Thanks

Comment: IF u want more efficient output add static, define static $getRow

Answer (score 1):

```
$fields = ' ` ' . implode('`, ` ', $func_get_args) . ' `';
```

this then makes you fields

```
` one `, ` two `
```

This should be

```
$fields = '`' . implode('`, `', $func_get_args) . '`';
```

ALSO

You do not need to put `''` around this

```
'`one`, `two`' < -WRONG
```

This is correct:

```
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT $fields FROM Login WHERE user_id = '$user_id' ");
```

Also LEARN PDO!!!

Comment: Hey thanks for the pointers.. I voted it up but I have to go with the guy that wrote the entire method for me! Thanks though

Comment: you shouldn't use his method in a real world example (or your own function!) - if it is a private site that is fine (not on the web just a local server) but MySQL is deprecated - plus your function is open to numerous different types of attack - mysqli and PDO are far better - glad it helped but keep learning and read about security and mysql injections! good luck

Answer (score 0):

Change this -

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT $fields FROM Login WHERE `user_id` = $user_id ");
```

Since a variable inside the double quotes echoes it. If you are using a string in `where` clause then you have to make it like this `'".$xyz['name']."'`. If its a simple integer like `user_id`, you can avoid writing in double or single quotes.`